# Weblogic 12.2 ignore @EJB annotation

Tags: jakarta-ee, ejb, weblogic

I'm migration an application from weblogic 10.3 to weblogic 12.2.

I include an library that is shared with other projects. This jar contains some POJOs with @EJB annotation in that look like this:

```
public abstract BaseSpecialService{
   @EJB DelegateService injectedService;
}
```

Note this is just a POJO: it doesn't have the @Stateless or @Stateful annotation. 
The idea is when I want to use this service, I extend it with a concrete @Stateless Bean class in another ejb-jar. But I only want to this for the services I need, the other services should be treated as POJOS.

In weblogic 10 this works just fine, but when moving to weblogic 12, I can't deploy the app because the container tries to inject the DelegateService in my example above, even though the @EJB annotation is not in an EJB but in a POJO. I get this error on deployment:

> [J2EE:160200]Error resolving ejb-ref
>   "com.example.BaseSpecialService/injectedService" from module "null" of
>   application "myapp-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT". The ejb-ref does not have an
>   ejb-link and the JNDI name of the target bean has not been specified.
>   Attempts to automatically link the ejb-ref to its target bean failed
>   because no EJBs in the application were found to implement the
>   "com.example.DelegateService" interface. Link or map this ejb-ref to
>   its target EJB and ensure the interfaces declared in the ejb-ref are
>   correct.

My interpretation is that in java EE 7 the all jars get scanned for annotations, while in java EE 5, only the jars that are marked as ejb modules in the application.xml get scanned. I'm looking for a way to stop the application server to inject dependencies into my POJOs and treat the shared library jar as a normal jar, not as an ejb-jar. But I can't find anything to do this. 
Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems the CDI container of the WebLogic scans your jar file and tries to inject POJOs/EJBs into them. My suggestion is to disable CDI scanning for given jar files and see the result. You can do this by adding a file named **beans.xml** containing following content and put it in the META-INF folder of your jar file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_1.xsd"
    version="1.1" bean-discovery-mode="none">
</beans>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Unfortunately that doesn't help :( I also tried to put a explicitly mark the jar as a <java> module in the application.xml, but that doesn't change anything. I'll refactor the jar into smaller jars and try to deploy that way

Comment: In the end it turns out your solution is correct. I just put the beans.xml in the wrong location: it has to be included in the jar that contains the classes containing annotations that get picked up by CDI, and not in the war/ejb jar that uses those jars. Thanks a lot for your answer!